# Checking permissions in accessors in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, permissions

I want to check does user have proper permission to get specific attribute from the `User` model.

I already did example simple accessor, but it is not sufficient, because it doesn't remove/unset `email` attribute from the `User` collection.

```php
public function getEmailAttribute($value)
{
   if(Auth::User()->hasPermissionTo('users.show.email')) {
     return $value;
   }
   return false;
}
```

then I use `User::Get()` and I get this output:

```
"name": "admin",
"email": "false",
...
```

Accessor works almost properly, but I want to hide `email` attribute at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by overriding the `toJson` or `toArray` method of the model itself, depending on which one you use. So for example the `toJson` can look like this:

```
public function toJson( $options = 0 )
{
    if( ! auth()->user()->hasPermissionTo('users.show.email')) {
        $this->hidden[] = 'email';     
    }
    return parent::toJson($options);
}
```

Notice I use the inverse logic, because in any case you would want to return a result. Same will be for the `toArray`. You should have this in your `User` model.

Comment: Thank you very much <3 You are awesome